# Is it possible to start preloading an spa (from a previous page)

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, preload

Is there anyway to preload an SPA (and all its javascript dependencies) before you navigate to the SPA from a previous page. For example, lets say you're on https://hello.mydomain.com and you expect the user to navigate to https://test.mydomain.com (which loads another SPA). Is there anyway to trigger a preloading/downloading of https://test.mydomain.com (especially the javascript) while you're on https://hello.mydomain.com? Maybe using a service worker or some other technique?